# Showing that $2\sin(x) + 3\cos(x) = x$ has three solutions

Tags: real-analysis

Using the IVT, show that $2\sin(x) + 3\cos(x) = x$ has three solutions

How does one apply the IVT to prove a function has three solutions? In Calc I, we only deal with proving there is at least one solution. We do this by considering the interval $[a,b]$ and calculating $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ to show there exists some $y=N$ that crosses the function bounded between those two values. But with three solutions...I'm at a loss.

Comment: Your title has no $3$, but your body does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: There are exactly three solutions to the equation $f(x) = 2\sin(x)+3\cos(x)-x = 0$. Try evaluating $f(x)$ at $x = -\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2},0, \pi$ to see if this might help.

Comment: So have have $\begin{matrix}
x & f(x) \\
\hline
-\pi & -3+\pi > 0 \\
-\pi/2 & -2+\pi/2 < 0 \\
0 & 3 > 0 \\
\pi & -3-\pi < 0
\end{matrix}$

Comment: This provides us with three closed intervals for where $f(x)$ passes through zero: $[-\pi,-\pi/2], [-\pi/2,0], [0,\pi]$. From here we can simply state the IVP to declare there is a solution in each interval?

Comment: Exactly! @Dylan

Comment: Although since the solutions don't exist at endpoints--as demonstrated, we know they exist on the interior of the given intervals, $(-\pi, -\pi/2), (-\pi/2,0), (0,\pi)$; which is an important distinction, if we just state there are zeros in each of the closed intervals, then $x=-\pi/2$ could for instance be a zero and we are then not guaranteed to have three distinct zeros. @Dylan